# Oracle trigger failed to access user_tab_columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am using Oracle 19c, and need to retrieve information from `user_tab_columns` in a trigger. There is no error when the trigger fires, however there is nothing returns back when query this system table.

```
create table mysche1.tb_test (id number(1), comment varchar2(20));

insert into mysche1.tb_test value (1, 'This is first line');



create or replace trigger mySche1.AUT_tb_test 
  after update on     
  mySche1.tb_test for each row
declare
  cursor vco_col_nm
  is
    select column_name 
      form user_tab_columns 
     where table_name = 'tb_test'

  colList varchar2(2048);
begin
  for colNm in vco_col_nm loop
    colList := colList || colNm.column_name || ',';
  end loop;

  mySche1.pack1.proc1 (colList); --I print out the colist in the PLSQL, which displays nothing.
end;

update mySche1.tb_test set comment = 'second' where id =1;
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: Can you check when you run this SQL , dose it return any rows "select column_name form user_tab_columns where table_name = 'tb_test' ", it could be you table name needs to be in upper case.

Comment: The statement returns the column names when ran it via sqlplus. However,  somehow the dbms_put.output does NOT work in the trigger. The DBMS console does not display any message from the trigger. So I am not able to debug it in the trigger.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4489025/trigger-nothing-returns-from-user-tab-columns#latest

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but **you must provide sufficient info to do so**. First, you ask for debug help, so take a look at [mre]. At least the code. Second, there is no such thing as the DBMS console. DBMS_OUTPUT is builds an internal buffer which the *client* can access after completion.  So what is your client and how do/did you tell is you wanted to process the DBMS output buffer? Finally, as @hkandpal pointed out the **table name must be upper case** since it was not  double quoted when created.

Comment: You also have a typo, `form` instead of `from`

Comment: You've added some code.  I formatted the code so that it's readable.  If you actually ran the code you provided, you'd get a compilation error because `from` is misspelled.  Assuming you fix that, if you ran the `select` statement alone, you'd get 0 rows because your table name isn't capitalized.  You say the statement works when run via `SQL*Plus` so maybe that's another typo you've introduced in posting your code?

Comment: By the way, it is generally considered poor practice to hardcode schema names in stored PL/SQL, unless of course there is some overriding reason why you have to.

Comment: The DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE works on sqlplus with SET SERVEROUTPUT ON.

Comment: YES. Because it is a SQL*Plus command, not PL/SQL. It tells the sqlplus, the client, to process the buffer created when the PLSQL completes.  If you use another client, then how that is accomplished may be completely different. However, many clients support set server output, others unfortunately do not,.